# Can't cast database type char to String

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core

With target framework netcoreapp3.1, using a PostgreSQL database with NpgSQL Nuget Package (v. 3.1.4), I have a column `my_column` with type `char` containing numbers and characters, e.g.:

```
> SELECT DISTINCT my_column FROM my_table;
  my_column 
-----------------------
 2
 1
 0
 d
```

When trying to access the properties with the Entity Framework :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyModel>(entity =>
{
  entity.Property(e => e.MyColumn)
   .HasColumnName("my_column")
   .HasColumnType("char");
}
```

With `MyModel` like:

```
public partial class MyModel
{
     public string MyColumn { get; set; }
}
```

I get this error (when requesting the data from my controller):

```
System.InvalidCastException: Can't cast database type char to String
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.GetFieldValue[T](Int32 ordinal)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.GetString(Int32 ordinal)
   at lambda_method(Closure , QueryContext , DbDataReader , ResultContext , Int32[] , ResultCoordinator )
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Controllers.Controller.Get() in ~/Controllers/Controller.cs:line 31
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutorAwaitable.Awaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Does this have to do with some `char`-values in my table are numbers? Or are they not casted correctly somewhere else?

Comment: Have you tried making the property `char` instead of `string`?

Comment: In `MyModel`? Yes, but I get the same error message. I believe the Entity Framework casts `char` to `string`, which I guess would generate a type error(?).

Comment: the tye of the property on your model is string. Try ("varchar").HasLength(50) or change the model property type to char

Comment: @Josh I´ve tried with `....HasColumnType("varchar").HasMaxLength(50);`, but same error message, or did you mean I should reference it somewhere else?

Comment: Please try to attribute your model with the following: `[Column(TypeName = "char(1)")]`

Comment: On `OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)` did you call `.UseNpgsql(...)`?

Comment: Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions and see if that helps.

Comment: @PeterCsala I tried that but still get the same error message.
@jegtugado Yes, I am connected and can access the table when excluding the `my_column`

Comment: @Jesper, when you change it to `char`,  what is the exception message? "Can't cast database type char to Char"?

Comment: I would suggest posting your issue to https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg instead of StackOverflow. Your code looks fine, to me at least, as it follows the [docs](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/basic.html) of using .NET string for PostgreSQL char.

Comment: @Andrew Nope, still Can't cast database type char to String, so the problem is probably with the value-conversion.

Comment: @jegtugado True, just wanted to check if I missed something obvious first. Will do!

Comment: In your call stack, you see that there's a `lambda_method` and then a `GetString`. Are you accessing this field through a lambda query somewhere? Does the exception occur in that `modelBuilder` line or somewhere else? Did you see [this](https://entityframeworkcore.com/knowledge-base/48112953/invalidcastexception--can-t-cast-database-type-bpchar-to-char)? (accepted answer to the right)

Comment: @Andrew Don't know if the `lambda_method` referenced is the lamba-expression in the `Property`-method, but I'm not using any lambda query that I know of. I am making the result `ToList()` in my controller when requesting the field. I saw the linked answer, and can't find any relevant differences from my code.

Comment: What is it there at `Controller.cs:line 31`?

Comment: @Andrew
`
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<List<MyModel>> Get()
        {
            using (var context = new DbContext()) {
                return await Task.FromResult(context.MyModel.Take(1).ToList());
            }
        }
`

Comment: Not sure if it could help, but I would try `var r1 = context.MyModel;`, then `var r2 = r1.Take(1);` then `var r3 = r2.ToList();` and finally `Task.FromResult(r3)`, just to see where exactly the exception occurs, or at least find a workaround if it's a bug in the nuget package. BTW, why are you returning a list if it's just one element?

Comment: @Andrew It is surprisingly in the `ToList()` statement, wonder if the conversion to a List is the problem. About the take(1), just a temporary setting. Don't want to return the entire list in dev since it is quite large.

Comment: By looking at the stack trace, there's a `GetString` there. Looking at the [documentation](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/api/Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.html), there's both a `GetString` and a `GetChar`. Can you have access to the [package's source code](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/blob/cb270a8aa1e7fa9999a17a5a743d80d2ee9d347d/src/Npgsql/NpgsqlDataReader.cs), to see why it's calling the former and not the latter?